# Unable to upload files (pdfs, images) larger than 1 MB

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have recently started PHP and Mysql project development on Ubuntu. In one part of the project I need to upload files. But my script is not uploading anything larger than 1 MB nor does it show any error. Smaller files are uploading fine. So I think my script is ok. Besides I have made suitable changes in both php.ini and my.cnf files. Can someone please tell me other possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in 2 ways, by editing the `php.ini` file or using `.htaccess`

If you edit the `php.ini` file which is located in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Find the value that says **upload_max_filesize** and change it to the value you wish, for example here I have a max upload file size of 100M

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Now you also need to edit the **post_max_size** that PHP will work with through POST, for that we edit the value to whatever you want, I recommend same as upload:

```
post_max_size = 100M
```

In the case you wish to do it with `.htaccess`, simply create this file in the root folder of you web site and add the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
    php_value post_max_size 100M
</IfModule>
```

Note that `.htaccess` does not work 100% of the time because it depends on Server settings. On your localhost it will work perfectly but if you are hosting on a shared site or an external address, the server might have limits to the max size that can be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

To show errors in PHP, edit your `php.ini` file and change:

```
display_errors = on
```

Restart your apache server.

Then in your project `config.php` file (if you have one), add these lines:

```
/* errors handling */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set('log_errors',0);
ini_set('error_log','path/to/log/file');
```

During development, set `display_errors=1` and `log_errors=0`.
When deployed, change `display_errors=0` and `log_errors=1`.

Then just be periodically checking your log file for any logged errors.